# Why does calling a function within define() break my site?

Tags: php

The following breaks my site quite badly:

```
define('FOO', get_foo());
```

However, the following works fine:

```
define('FOO', 'BAR');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [define()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) expects a value for the constant and not the returned value of a function:

> The value of the constant; only scalar and null values are allowed.
>   Scalar values are integer, float, string or boolean values. It is
>   possible to define resource constants, however it is not recommended
>   and may cause unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use function in define, this is not good. Define is used to make constants. Constants must not be changed, must have the same value during all the time. Functions, like get_foo(), can return different values. Php thinks that you want to put changable value to the constant. Try to put the result if this function to the variable:

```
$foo = get_foo();
```

Comment: But I want to use define to define the returned value once as it is used 5 times in a php script. I don't really want to call this function several times as it will be slow.

Comment: @Nadine Then do as he suggested: Store the value of the function in a variable and then call `define()`. Btw, you shouldn't use define like this and no, calling functions several times (usually) shoudln't be slow. Smells more like a bad design…